# Optimal query to match two array of objects key in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c7c4ee66cfea38a0e7c123b"),
"id" : 1,
"teachersAvailable" : {
    "location" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 1,

        }, 
        {
            "id" : 2
        }
    ]
}
}
```

This is how my MongoDB structure looks like (one of the documents in my collection).
I am making a POST request with an argument of JSON of the following structure

```
{'id':1,'locations':[{'id':1, 'value':'xyz'},{'id':2, 'value':'def'},{'id':3, 'value':'abc'}]}
```

I want to find those documents whose 'location.id' (in my mongodb) matches to my JSON's 'locations.id'
is it possible to write this directly in Mongo Query? or do i have to iterate?

EDIT: I meant if any of the location.id of my JSON matches with Mongo's locations.id, i wanna return the document

Comment: See [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Comment: @NeilLunn I am using $in, but how can I trigger object keys using it?
I mean i was doing 'teachersAvailable.location.id' : { '$in' : arg['locations'] }
but how can I trigger 'id' key of objects of locations

Comment: See [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)